# ShinyApp reactive error while trying to select variables from imported data set

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest

I am very new to Shiny and R in general and I am building an app that allows users to import data, select their variables, number of trees.. ect and then run that through a random forest script and have it display the outputs. Right now I am just working on the inputs, however, I am running into a problem. The user can import a CSV but then they cannot select their variables (headers from csv). I am trying to make it reactive so the user first must import their csv before the option of selecting their variables pops up (seems simple).

Here is my code right now:
    [ui.R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unE11.png)

[server.R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6xcB.png)

[Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTTsq.png)

I am probably just making a silly mistake because I am unfamiliar with Shiny but your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy input and outputs in your post?

Answer (score 0):

#### A little background info

First off, I recommend you read this through to get a good understanding of reactivity in Shiny: [Shiny Reactivity Overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). This helps a lot with variable scoping in a Shiny context too: [Scoping Rules in Shiny Apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

#### The issue

I believe this issue is due to you defining the variable `file_to_read` within the scope of shiny output: `output$input_file` in your server.R file. When the function `read.table()` looks for the variable `file_to_read`, it doesn't exist since it is only defined within the scope of the shiny output.

Try making a reactive value and then assigning the `input$file` value to it once it is uploaded by the user. You'll also have to convert your dat1 variable to a shiny reactive since you can only read reactive values in the context of other reactive sources (e.g. observe(), reactive(), observeEvent(), etc.)

```
file_to_read <- reactiveVal(NULL) # Set the value to NULL to initialize

output$input_file <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return () # Check there is an input file
    file_to_read(input$file) # Set the reactiveVal to the input file
})

# Make dat1 a reactive so it can be read within a shiny reactive
dat1 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(file_to_read()) return (NULL) # Check for input file in reactiveVal  
    read.table(file_to_read()$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header)
})  
# Make an eventReactive to capture when there is read.table() data from dat1
reactive1 <- eventReactive(dat1, {
    if (is.null(dat1)) return ()
    D <- colnames(dat1)  
    return (list(D, D[1]))
})
```

I didn't test this code since you posted your data in image format and I don't have an input file, but hope this helps your error.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to help! Still having a little trouble but reading those articles does help clear some things up. Im going to link the input and output files this next time to give people a better idea of what is happening.